# Configuration and the mapping of constant memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'd like to know if the configuration of constant memory changes as the underlying architecture evolves from Kepler to Volta. To be specific, I have two questions:

1) Does the sizes of constant memory and per-SM constant cache change?

2) What's the mapping from the cmem space to constant memory?

When compiling cuda code to PTX with adding '-v' to nvcc, we can see the memory usage like: ptxas info : Used 20 registers, 80 bytes cmem[0], 348 bytes cmem[2]. So does the cmem space maps to constant memory? Does accessing to each cmem space  go through the on-chip constant cache?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer for the 1st question.
In the CUDA C Programming Guide, [table14](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/8.0/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities) shows the size of constant memory and constant cache for different CCs.
    The constant memory size is always 64KB from CC2.x to 6.x. The on-chip constant cache size is 8KB till CC 3.0 and increases to 10KB for the later.

Comment: Please  add the relevant information here, not just the link.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry for that. I have added the relevant information.